# Opencart image manager is not loading

Tags: php, opencart

it was ok just a few days ago, but suddenly it is not working, 
here is a screen shot of console log error msg.

[image]

Comment: there's no way to debug a server error without inspecting the error log

Comment: ok, I'm replying the error_message after reading the error_log file...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a lot of images in single folder so image-manager try to proceed all of them. It can cause error (for example) memory overload
See server logs to be sure

Comment: no, I always nest images creating different folders.